# Encouter prevented webview navigation when using webview api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hi I am using vscode webview api to show some webpages from local server

the key part (form) of the source code of the webpage is like this. It has a button and will launch a post request when clicked. therefore it can update its content

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="start">Start Date:</label><input id="name" type="date" name="start" value="2019-01-01"
            class="form-control"><label for="end">End Date:</label><input id="name" type="date" name="end" value="2019-01-04"
            class="form-control"></div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">generate report</button>
```

it works fine when opening with browser. But when launching it in vscode, nothing shows and vscode tells me it prevented webview navigation when using webview api

the part of code that using webview api is like this

```
    public async showDetailedReport(){
    const param: IRequestParam ={
        endpoint:'localhost',
        method:'GET',
        port:23333,
        path:'/report/detailReport'
    };
    try{
        const html: string = await sendRequest(param);
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
            'Report',
            'Report',
            vscode.ViewColumn.One,
            {
                enableScripts:true,
            }
        );
        panel.webview.html = html;
    } catch(e){
        await vscode.window.showErrorMessage(e);
    }
}
```

So my question is why that happen and how to solve it, which I mean, to send post or redirected to other webpages. Anything can be helpful. Thanks with grateful.

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.31, webviews may only display a page of html content and may not navigate to other resources (such as making a POST request using a form).

You can still make requests using `fetch` or similar APIs, but standard POST submit form will not work.